# Is there a way to enumerate object parts in one request?

Tags: amazon-s3

Lets say I have an object that was created using multipart upload and it has 2000 parts. I need to figure out each part size. I can do 2000 requests like this one:

`HEAD /<object-key>?partNumber=...`

and use returned `Content-Length`.

Is it possible to get all this information using one (or fewer than 2000) requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that. In fact, in order to get parts count you need to submit `HEAD` or `GET` request that contains `partNumber` even if object was uploaded in a single `PUT` -- for such objects `partNumber=1` is ok, but anything else will produce an error.